# passing object across controllers in grails

Tags: grails

I have the domain classes `TestUnit`, `TestParameter` and `ParameterRange` as shown below.

```
class TestUnit {
    static hasMany = [testParameters : TestParameter]
}

class TestParameter {
    static hasMany = [paramRanges : ParameterRange ]
    static belongsTo = [testUnit : TestUnit]
}

class ParameterRange {
    static belongsTo = [testParam : TestParameter]
}
```

I want to add the `TestUnit` object (i.e, `testUnitInstance.id`) in the `ParameterRangeController`.

Since i'm new to grails i don't know how to do that could anyone please explain it to me?

What I've tried:

```
def testUnitId = params.testUnitId 
def testUnitInstance = TestUnit.get(testUnitId) 
def testParameterInstance = TestParameter.get(params.id) 
[parameterRangeInstanceList: testParameterInstance.paramRanges, parameterRangeInstance: new ParameterRange(),testParameterInstance:testParameterInstance, page:"Range", testUnitInstance:testUnitInstance]
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I think it must be something basic. I would recommend you take a tutorial in "Beginning with Grails". They will show you how to make a CRUD interface for simple web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate more than one domain class in a controller or service, there's no restriction to that.

```
class ParameterRangeController {
  def show() {
    //you can get other domain classes...
    TestUnit theUnit = TestUnit.get(1)
    render view: 'show', model: [theUnit:theUnit, ...]
  }
}
```

Since `TestUnit` is related to `TestParameter`, you can also access it like:

```
ParameterRange range = ParameterRange.get(1)
println range.testParam.testUnit
```

I suggest you to take a look in [the docs about GORM](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html), there's a lot of useful info.

Comment: ya thank so much this is what i have done in list action but when i print theUnit it shows null

Comment: def testUnitId = params.testUnitId
  def testUnitInstance = TestUnit.get(testUnitId)
  def testParameterInstance = TestParameter.get(params.id)
  [parameterRangeInstanceList: testParameterInstance.paramRanges, parameterRangeInstance: new ParameterRange(),testParameterInstance:testParameterInstance, page:"Range", testUnitInstance:testUnitInstance]                                                    sorry for asking more question rather than searching docs about gorm

Comment: Probably params.testUnitId is null?

Comment: how to an object using it id, i have a drop down menu, i want to get the object of that using its id

Comment: @John I suggest you to create another question, with the code that you already tried and not works.